# Is it possible to deploy a rails project from windows to linux server with postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql

When I tried to deploy a rails project from windows local environment to linux(CentOS6.5) server, I got a error from capistrano 3.

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
```

I had a `gem 'pg'` in `Gemfile` though. I found a line that cause the problem in `Gemfile.lock`.

`pg (0.17.1-x86-mingw32)`

When I removed `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` in another linux virtual host, the problem was solved. But I couldn't find out the way how to solve it in windows.

As far as I understand, I must send `Gemfile.lock` to server if I use `Capistrano`.
And `Gemfile.lock` created in windows is incompatible with one created in linux or osx.

Is there no way to deploy from windows to linux server with postgres by using capistrano?

Comment: If you run bundle install on the server, this will install a fresh batch of gems as per the environment, right? Have you tried using `bundle install RAILS_ENV=production` after Capistrano has pushed the code?

Comment: @Paven sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @Tetsu Don't be sorry.We do mistakes.We are Humans after all :)

Comment: @Rich I got the error, when capistrano run `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet`. And I've run same command directly by logging server, then got same error. I understand the command is same function of `bundle install RAILS_ENV=production`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's the same, but I figured if you ran bundle install from the `shell`, you'd have a fresh environment to install from.

Comment: Are you using `pg` in local, or just in production?

Comment: I meant by expression `by logging server`, it is from the `shell`. And `Gemfile.lock` is for preventing the "fresh environment". Of course if I delete `Gemfile.lock` then `bundle install` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been an issue with bundler for many years: current open 'issue' on github: https://github.com/bundler/bundler-features/issues/4

original issue (4 years old) : https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/646

- if you scroll down pretty far there is a capistrano hack to autofix up the Gemfile.lock, might be worth trying

Looks like Heroku actually removes Gemfile.lock if it references Windows specific gems

From: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

> Be as specific in your Gemfile as you possibly can when developing on Windows. If only one developer on your team has a Windows machine, consider not checking in their Gemfile.lock changes or manually bundle installing and committing on a non-Windows machine before deploying.

And https://ninefold.com/ has similar recommendation: hacking the Gemfile.lock

https://help.ninefold.com/hc/en-us/articles/201335424-Deploying-a-Windows-Created-Rails-App

Answer (score 0):

there is no matter if you use windows/linux/mac to run capistrano scripts.

Please provide full system details(the remote machine).

did you installed ruby there using what (RVM/rbenv)?

do you have all the native extensions to build the gems on the machine?

http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/04/05/rails-deployment-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-dot-3/

see the above link and try the config your system(this use Capistrano 2 but use your scripts just build the machine as written in the article)